# How to space out an array in perl?

Tags: perl

I have an array that goes something like:

```
A B C D E F G H A1 B1 C1 D1 E1 F1 
G1 H1
```

I was wondering how I could split it up so that it prints a new line when it hits A1. 
Note that this isn't actually how it looks like, but rather a convoluted table that mixes a lot of numbers and letters (if it matters in any way).

Comment: You mean you have a list of distinct values a, b, c, d or you have a string that is "a b c d e f"

Comment: Please show code that exemplifies creating the array.  And how do you recognize when to split a line? Do you need to look for `$a[$i] eq 'A1'`, or is it after 8 elements, or what?

Comment: Distinct values of a,b,c,d... etc.

Comment: $test = join(" ",@problem);
@problems = split(" ", $test);
$i = 4;
$a = @problems;
while ($i < $a) { @problems[$i]=@problems[$i]*86400;
$i=$i+9;} 

That's what I did, and it's after the 9th element I believe

Comment: Think what rule you would use mentally to identify points where a newline should be inserted.  Then program that rule.  This is one of countless situations where a clear understanding of the specification is 9/10ths of the problem.

Comment: does "hits A1" mean before the A1 or after?

Answer (score 2):

Assume that you have all letters+numbers in one line `$line`. So:

```
my $line = 'A B C D E F G H A1 B1 C1 D1 E1 F1 A2 B2';
my ($curr_n, $last_n) = (0, 0);
foreach my $el (split(/ /, $line)) {
    $curr_n = $el =~ /\w+(\d+)/ ? $1 : 0;
    if ($curr_n != $last_n) {
        $last_n = $curr_n;
        print "\n";
    }
    print $el;
}
```

It gives follow output:

```
ABCDEFGH
A1B1C1D1E1F1
A2B2
```